# DOMException: Invalid property name on dataset

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I receive "**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'child-count' property on 'DOMStringMap': 'child-count' is not a valid property name.**" when the following code is executed:

```
elem.dataset['child-count'] = "test";
```

where elem is a HTMLElement.

Thought it is legit to use the '-' character within data-attribute names or am I missing something else?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) properties are camel-cased: `elem.dataset.childCount`. They are implicitly transformed to hyphenated attribute names (`data-child-count` in your case).

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.